# Validate existing email in mysql in a node.js server

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am having the following problem with node and mysql:
I have a function registerUser that takes the req.body with the user credentials and store them into a mysql db.
First of all I check that the email provided does not already exist. I have done this validation working with postgres  in the following manner: if(user.rows.lenght!==0) return res.send("user already exist")
Then I pass to the next line of code that insrts the credentials into the db.
My problem is that using mysql, user.rows is undefined. I am having trouble extracting the data from the response which would allowme to perform some sort of validation.
My code is like this:

```
registerUser:async(req,res)=>{
        const resolver=Resolver(res)
        try {
        //get data from req.body
           const {userName, userEmail, userPassword}=req.body
        //Check if user alreday exist on db by email
        const user=db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=?",
        [userEmail],(err,result)=>{
            if(err) console.log(err)
            else if(result.length!==0) return res.status(401).send('user already exist')
        })
```

The callback function of the query does not stop the execution of the registeruser function. Also, the result comes with the user credentaials which is what I need, but I dont know how to extract it from the callback in order to use it in the scope of registerUser

Comment: Your db.query seems faulty. You need to put the value of userEmail in place of ?. This causes the if to always evaluate to false, but you don't send / do anything when it doesn't exist.To debug, log "result" for a known e-mail address. You will see that nothing is returned.

Comment: The query works . The result argument in the callback function actually returns the user that corresponds to the email in req.body. Yet, I dont know how to extract result from the callback and use it in the scope of the main function.